# Acer Aspire 1360 graphic driver problem (half black screen)

Tags: screen, aspire

I have an Acer Aspire 1360 and half my screen is black, I cannot change my resolution because then my computer freezes. I am running the lastest Ubuntu and have tried anything any advice. I've also searched forums and many have this problem but couldn't find a fix and Ubuntu is impossible to use like this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running 2 graphic cards in SLI Mode?

Answer (score 1):

Try restart lightdm:

after boot press:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> (or another one)

then login and type: `sudo restart lightdm`

Hope it helps. (it does for me: eee-pc 1101ha)

Comment: Worked like a charm !!!! This should be set fixed !